# Efficient use of cross apply?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a subquery which will do a `LEFT JOIN` on three different tables. I then have a fourth table which is joined on an id that exactly one of the three tables I previously joined will contain.

```
SELECT 
(
    IIF 
    ( 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM A
        LEFT JOIN B ON
            (A.Col1 = B.Col1)
        LEFT JOIN C ON
            (A.Col2 = C.Col2)
        LEFT JOIN D ON
            (A.Col3 = D.Col3)
        LEFT JOIN E ON
            (B.SomeID = E.SomeID)
            OR
            (C.SomeID = E.SomeID)
            OR 
            (D.SomeID = E.SomeID)
        WHERE A.SomeCondition = T.SomeCondition
       1,
       0
) AS SomeCol
FROM T
WHERE T.Col1 = (some condition)
```

Would I benifit in performance if i did a `CROSS APPLY` when I limit the rows on Table A when I do `WHERE A.SomeCondition = T.SomeCondition`. This table will have significantly more rows then the other tables.

Comment: Getting rid of a `select*` from 4 tables would help with the performance.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the question.

Comment: Does this run? How are you aliasing a `Select *` into one column, `SomeCol` ?

Comment: Just a note, the `APPLY` equivalent of a `LEFT JOIN` is `OUTER APPLY`, not `CROSS`

Answer (score 1):

This code returns data even if table E doesn't have a match.

Instead of

```
LEFT JOIN E ON
    (B.SomeID = E.SomeID)
    OR
    (C.SomeID = E.SomeID)
    OR 
    (D.SomeID = E.SomeID)
```

You could try:

```
INNER JOIN E on e.id = coalesce(B.SomeID, C.SomeID, D.SomeID)
```

Then start looking at the query plan and see what it shows for your data.